# IQueryable vs IEnumerable and polymorphism where an object knows which subclass it is

Tags: c#, linq, oop, ienumerable, iqueryable

When explicitly declaring the type of a query with `IEnumerable` such as

```
IEnumerable<string> q = 
    from c in db.Customers      
    select c.ContactName;   
var q2 = q.Where(s => s.StartsWith(start)); 
return q2;
```

The query will use `Enumerable.where`. Why doesn't the query know that it is `IQueryable` and use `Queryable.where`?

This seems contradictory to the OOP concepts where a child object declared with a parent type should know that it is actually the type of the child and use the child type's methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.Where` method on `IEnumerable<T>` is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8).

As a result, it can't be *virtual*.  Only virtual methods exhibit the polymorphism you are expecting

Comment: Wow, that makes sense! Thanks for the clear answer :)